# Ubuntu Version for my old hardware?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lubuntu

I having more than 100 computers in my office with old hardware Pentium 4, 1ghz processor, 512mb Ram. Needed software are Google chrome with flash plugins and open office. Kindly suggest me the stable version from ubuntu, that i could get updates for the above mentioned software.

Computers used for only data entry and Internet browsing purpose.

ACUBE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for **Lubuntu 14.04** - It is the lightest one with the support until 2019. Although it doesn't come with the software you mentioned you may install Open Office, flash and Chrome after the system installation.

**Xubuntu** may be the option, but needs 1gb RAM to run apps smoothly.

[Xubuntu system requirements](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/)

Comment: Where can i get Lubuntu 14.04, can i install it with 512mb

Comment: Thanks i got it from google  http://lubuntu.net/  and it can be installed with minimum 512mb ram,  Thanks Muzaffar

Comment: Go here: http://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/ Yes, you can.

Comment: i tried installing lubuntu 14.04, but during installation while creating the filesystem, i m getting a error like cannot create filesystem, but this computer was working fine with ubuntu 9.04 previously, what might be the problem?

Comment: Hard to say. Look through these links to see if you are doing everything correctly:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Absolute_Requirements   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1753447&highlight=root+file+system+defined   If it doesn't help try asking a new question, I suspect it already was asked but anyway you'll be guided to the right way by someone hopefully.